# Where to save user related settings parameters

Tags: cordova, local-storage

I have an app where user logs in and use several features. In the meantime, he can adjust some settings in a relevant screen (receive push notifications, post to facebook, post to twitter).

I am wondering where to save these parameters in order to stick with the logged in user, so that when another user log in, he can get his own relevant settings configured. And so on.

If I store that values to localStorage, they will be related always to the LAST logged in user, which is not a convenient way.

So shall I store that kind of data in my backend tables? (I am using parse BTW) and retrieve them each time the user log in ? Or there is another way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can either store those settings in `localStorage` (or any other persistent storage), but key each setting to the user, or store the settings in the cloud. The latter works well if users might expect their settings to follow them to other devices they are using, but you'll need to be **very clear you are doing this**.

As for keeping the settings local, why not this?

`localStorage.setItem ( userName, JSON.stringify( { postToTwitter: true, postToFacebook, false, ... } ) );`

And later, to retrieve:

`var userSettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem ( userName ));
if (userSettings.postToTwitter) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, I am not worried about the implementation rather than I am concerned by the design approach which should be usually followed in such case. Based on your answer, I think sticking with the cloud choice (parse.com in my case) is the best way to work. I am still opened on other approaches if they do exist though. Thanks

Comment: In today's world of cloud sync services, I wouldn't be surprised that your users might not expect the settings to follow them wherever they go. So using Parse is the best option.

Comment: BUT: Craft a privacy policy and be very careful about how you communicate this to your users. If there's any chance the information could be personally identifying, the user needs to have a way to opt-out if they feel uncomfortable sending that information across the wire.